# Problem using "-" inside \textbf

Tags: bold, punctuation

I hope you can help me with this. I have the following in my code:

```
\textbf{Legendre–Fenchel transformation}
```

The problem is that the `-` doesn't show up after compilation. Instead it comes out as LegendreFenchel. How can I remedy this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Does the problem show up also in normal text?

Comment: @How are you typing the dash (I can see the problem, it must be some unicode issue). Cut and paste this \textbf{Legendre--Fenchel transformation}, it should work.

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I am new to this forum. I don't get any error messages. Its just that the output doesn't contain the - symbol as it should. By the way, I should probably add that that piece of code is within an \item in the itemize environment. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides ... probably make it an answer so Nik can accept it and the question is cleared ... ?

Comment: @tohecz The question could also be closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably some input encoding issue, as I could reproduce it by cut and pasting into a minimal. If you cut and paste this:

```
 \textbf{Legendre--Fenchel transformation},
```

it works.